# RoR: how to catch any route that didn't match route config and redirect to homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

For example in routes i have such code:

```
get "profile/:id" => 'profiles#show', as: :profile

root 'articles#index'
```

but how could i catch such kind of url and redirect to home:

i need to catch any non existing route. Why i need this? via SEO rules. Becouse for example now if i enter `url.com/?porn or url.com/profile?1&azaza` - i will be on page where i entered this ugly url. But i need to redirect to home, so that any "hacker" didn't not post illegal link's on they resources...

is it real to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different cases you need to take care of

- a wrong path
- a wrong resource

For the first one, you can add a global match rule at the end of the routes.

```
match '*foo', to: 'articles#index'
```

Then you should handle the missing resources in your controllers.

eg

```
def show
  begin
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  rescue
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Of course if you have multiple controllers and need to repeat that in many places you should use a more general approach. Perhaps rescuing `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` on your `ApplicationController`